# AWS S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, amazon-iam

What I want to do is list all the contents of a bucket, except from the contents of a specific folder (archive). The problem is when I "ls" the bucket, I also get the files from the "archive" folder. This is my current setup:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt1382452205000",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
      ],
      "Condition":{
          "StringNotLike":{"s3:prefix":["archive/"]}
       },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ExplictDenyAccessToArchive",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/archive/*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyListBucketOnArchive",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"],
      "Condition":{
          "StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["archive/"]}
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this an IAM user policy or a group policy or a bucket policy?  Are you trying to restrict yourself from accessing part of a bucket that you own?

Comment: This is a group policy. I want to exclude a group of users listing a subfolder

Answer (score 2):

The ListBucket action in IAM policies applies at the bucket level. You cannot grant it on a subset of the bucket.

It sounds like your goal is to exclude files from a file listing rather than restrict access to the user.  Unfortunately the S3 api does not let you specify prefixes to exclude.  You could however use the API's delimiter option to get a top level listing of all the top level paths, and then make follow up calls using the prefix and marker parameters to only list the paths you are interested.

More details at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListBucket.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I've done so far, I thought it would be good if I eliminate some list requests..